# How to make column hidden in jsGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I am using jsGrid in my project and now I am stuck here to hide a column that is being used in code but should not be displayed in page.

**The grid I am using is : [jsGrid](http://js-grid.com/)**

I have tried to take input control `hidden` but, still it doesn't work.

The following code is defines the columns of grid where I have taken hidden field for `AccountID`. but, it doesn't work.

**Code:**

```
fields: [
        { name: "Account", width: 150, align: "center" },
        { name: "Name", type: "text" },
        { name: "AccountID", type: "hidden", width: 0}
    ]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this below code.

create a css class like below

```
.hide
{
   display:none;
}
```

And assign the css property to the field like below

```
fields: [
    { name: "Account", width: 150, align: "center" },
    { name: "Name", type: "text" },
    { name: "AccountID", css: "hide", width: 0}
]
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 15):

Since v1.3 jsGrid fields have an option `visible`

http://js-grid.com/docs/#fields

If you need to hide (or show) a field at runtime, it can be done like the following:

```
$("#grid").jsGrid("fieldOption", "ClientName", "visible", false);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
fields: [
{ name: "Account", width: 150, align: "center" },
{ name: "Name", type: "text" },
{ name: "AccountID", visible: false, width: 0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    fields: [{
            name: "<FIELD NAME>",
            visible: false
        }
    ]
```

Comment: please explain why this code solves the problem. Please look at [answer]

Answer (score 0):

hidden very simple, make it like this example :

`{ name: "id", title: "Id", type: "text", width: 1, css:"hide"}`

where css class hide from bootsrap

Answer (score 0):

In my case we started our application to show a column in JSGrid and went all the way to production. Later there was a need to hide that column but I used that column to do custom sorting. So this is how I did

My styles

```
.idStyle:
{
  color: red;
}
```

Created new style

```
.hiddenStyle: 
{
  display: none;
}
```

Below are my jsGrid Fields

```
var jsGridField = 
[
  { name: "Student ID", type: "text", width: "auto", css: "idStyle hiddenStyle" },
  { name: "Student Name", type: "text", width: "auto", css: "labelStyle" },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
No data Row has been created on jsgrid for row data when there is no data. we have used below css row data for hiding it and showing.
<tr class="jsgrid-nodata-row"><td class="jsgrid-cell" colspan="16" style="width: 60.3958px;">Not found</td></tr>

When row data taking time to display by a API call , we are showing spinner on the grid, but user has been shown as no data found .. so which is not a best user experience . 

For solving this we can use hide and show the css element on modifying the CSS class

For Hiding : 
$('.jsgrid-nodata-row').hide();
$('.jsgrid-cell').hide();

For Showing : 
$('.jsgrid-nodata-row').show();
$('.jsgrid-cell').show();
```